# Dilate/Erode image in Shader Editor?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, vector, vector-mapping

In the compositor you can dilate/erode an image based on pixel brightness, like this :

[image]

I'm wondering if there is a way to do the same in the Shader Editor (maybe with some clever vector math?).

I'm not aiming at the blocky aspect of it but just a way to expand the colors of an image texture, such that brighter colors expand over darker colors.

I imagine it would involve something in the likes of transforming colors into vectors but in such a way that the resulting vector field would translate each point along the normal of its color's "boundary line", if that makes sense.

Any vector ninja in the place who has an idea on this?